# Require answer of radio button to go to the next page in HTML

Tags: html, radio-button

I would like to make sure subjects answer my radio button question on my online survey in order to be able to go to the next page. If they don't answer, I would like to have a pop up message that says "Please answer the question."

This is the code I have, and where I would like to put the requirement:

```
<div class="page" id="6" style="display: none;">
    <div class="cell">  
        <div align="center">
        <h1>Do you hear a speech disfluency?</h1></div>    
        <br />
        <audio src="sw2368_so_we-ve_got_you_know_we-ve_got.mp3" type="audio/mp3" preload="auto" controls="controls" oncontextmenu="return false;">Audio could not be loaded.</audio>
        <br />
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
            <input name="Q1Answer" type="radio" value="Y" />Yes</label>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
            <input name="Q1Answer" type="radio" value="N" />No</label>
        </div>
        <br />
    </fieldset>
    <input type="button" value="Continue" onclick="next();" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: What's the contents of your next() function?

Comment: Your HTML is not _well-formed_, because the `<fieldset>` tag is closed but not opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Alternative 1.** You can have one of them defaultly checked when page is opened by adding `checked` so it'll be like this:

```
<div class="radio">
<label><input name="Q1Answer" type="radio" value="Y" checked/>Yes</label>
</div>
```

Or ...

**Alternative 2.** Add this line in the first line of next() function:
If you use jQuery:

```
if (!$('input[name=Q1Answer]:checked').length) return;
```

It'll prevent next() function to continue executing when there's no radio button checked.

**UPDATE:**
Sorry I forgot that you want to popup a message. So just add this:

```
if (!$('input[name=Q1Answer]:checked').length) {
     alert("Please answer the question.");
     return;
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**
If you don't use jQuery, this is the pure javascript solution:

Just need to change the if condition to this:

```
if (!document.querySelectorAll('input[name=Q1Answer]:checked').length) {
     alert("Please answer the question.");
     return;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you quick answer @Taufik. I like your second alternative a lot because it does not bias for a default answer. Is there a way to embed the if statement inside the 'onclik next' function?
For example:
<input type="button" value="Continue" onclick="function filledOut(id) { return document.getElementById(id).value != 'default' } if(filledOut('lang1') && filledOut('country')) { next(); }else{ alert('Please answer all of the questions marked with an asterisk (*).'); }"  />

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it helped :) Yes you can put it inside onclick attribute just like this: `onclick="if (!document.querySelectorAll('input[name=Q1Answer]:checked').length) alert('Please answer the question.'); else goto_nextpage();"`

Comment: still I don't recommend you or anybody to put whole function inside onclick attribute like your example, use onclick just to call function.

Comment: Thanks again! This is very helpful. I followed your advice, and am posting the code in case it is useful to anyone else:
<input type="button" value="Continue" onclick="go_next();" />

<script>
function go_next() {

if (!document.querySelectorAll('input[name=Q1Answer]:checked').length) {
     alert("Please answer the question.");
     return;
}
else{
next(); 
}
}
</script>

Comment: Then make this as approved answer if you don't mind :))

Comment: Just did it! Sorry new at this :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the required-attribute for one input of the radiogroup, but you can set it for all.

For example:

```html
<form>
  <label for="input1">1:</label>
  <input type="radio" name="myradiogroup1" id="input1" value="1" required><br>

  <label for="input2">2:</label>
  <input type="radio" name="myradiogroup1" id="input2" value="2"><br>

  <label for="input3">3:</label>
  <input type="radio" name="myradiogroup1" id="input3" value="3"><br>

  <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you! This code does not work for me because I want to go to the next page and not to submit. If I change the input to <input type="button" value="Continue" onclick="next();" /> the required field does not force answering and allows going to the next page